# Google Adwords implementation via GTM - Please suggest correct implementation

Tags: google-tag-manager, google-ads-api

I am trying to audit Google dynamic Remarketing tag on our website. It is done via GTM and from what i've read online, instead of using data layer passed through codebase variables it is using custom javascript. Below is the way it's implemented which is confusing. i just want to know if this is correct way of implementation or should i re do the tag?

we have a custom javascript variable "google_tag_params"
[image: javascript variable - google_tag_params]

Then we have adwords Remarketing tag implemented which references data layer variable "google_tag_params" that fires on all pages

[image: Adwords -Remarketing Tag]

Then we have several other gtm tags : homepage, products, cart etc (custom html type) that populates the google_tag_params. Below is an example for the homepage which fires on homepage and products

[image: adwords- homepage]

[image: adwords-product]

Products

Any documentation which explains this current implementation will be helpful.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks like a working implementation, although it negates pretty much all advantages of having a tag management system.

Remarketing attributes different weights to users depending on which pages they have visited - a user who has just looked briefly at the homepage is less valuable than a user who has looked at product categories or product details (plus the more you know about the products viewed the more precise you can tailor the ads to your clients taste, or so the theory goes). This is why you need to pass in data about the sites visited and the products viewed via a javascript object - the "google_tag_params".

Usually the data for this would be provided in the source code of your website - ideally in the datalayer format, although a global javascript variable works as well.

Apparently the site you are looking at does not do that. So the person who implemented this used custom HTML tags to create global JS variables with the necessary data. This puts the data in the global namespace. Then (s)he created a javascript variable that reads the js variable created from the tag and feeds it to the Adwords tag.

There are multiple custom HTML tags with definitions for the google_tag_params. I am pretty sure that if you look at the triggers you will see that they are fired on specific pages - "Homepage" only at the root page of your website, "Products Variables" on product details pages etc. That way the google_tag_params object contains the data that is required for the respective page type. Since the website does not provide product data there is some custom javascript in the "Products Variables" tag to extract data from the DOM.

Does this work ? Well, I guess so. Is it elegant ? Certainly not - two of the main advantages of GTM are encapsulation (the only global variable you need is the datalayer array, thus mitigating the risk of naming collisions) and a fairly robust selector engine. Your code as it is uses none of that.

Is is worth changing ? Maybe, a little. It would be a little more elegant if the google_tag_params would be created in a custom javascript variable (which takes the format of an anonymous function that returns a value). Also the DOM extraction code could be moved either to custom javascript variables or DOM type variables (which reads data from HTML elements without any custom code if you can come up with the proper selector). However while this means you have a nicer and marginally more reliable implementation this means some effort for basically the same outcome.

However a proper implementation would rely on a datalayer that is provided by your page (i.e. it is created via server-side code). DOM extraction is a fickle business and if you change your markup you will break your Adwords tracking.

If you cannot have a dataLayer implemented via server-side code then the pragmatic solution would probably be to leave things as they are. It does leave you open to a few problems (if you change the markup or introduce a global JS variable named "price" or "qty" then your implementation is screwed) but apparently this has done its job so far, so why go the extra mile.

Comment: Thanks Eike for one awesome explanation!